# Calculating current velocity of a falling object

Tags: ruby, physics, game-physics

I'm attempting to calculate the speed of a sky diver first with no chute and once deployed the  object should decelerate until it reaches it's terminal velocity again. However in attempting this I've ran into some problems.

- First of the maximum calculated velocity seems to have a higher max
  than the terminal velocity I calculate for it.
- Secondly when decelerating (e.g. the cross_sectional_area is increase and/or the drag_coefficient) the drag force explodes! It gets so big
  that the player is probably rocketed into space if not completed
  squashed.

Code:

```
drag_coefficient     = 1.5.to_f
mass                 = 100.to_f
cross_sectional_area = 0.7.to_f
GRAVITY              = 9.8.to_f 
density              = 1.2690.to_f # Air density
```

```
  def terminal_velocity
    ((2.to_f * mass * GRAVITY / (density * drag_coefficient * cross_sectional_area)) ** 0.5.to_f).to_f
  end

  # Air resistance in N
  def drag_force
    (0.5.to_f * drag_coefficient * density * cross_sectional_area * @velocity) ** 2
  end

  # Delta time in seconds
  def tick(delta_time)
    @velocity += (acceleration * delta_time)
  end

  # Acceleration in m/s
  def acceleration
    (gravitational_force - drag_force) / mass
  end

  # Gravitational force in N
  def gravitational_force
    mass * GRAVITY
  end
```

I've been looking into good sources for this but it's either quite dense on the Maths or it's totally oversimplified.

**Edit:** Just squared the velocity and this is what I get and it looks a lot better. (Thanks PinnyM!!)

Using these variables (Calculated with a 20ms tick but only plotted the whole second values):

```
GRAVITY              = 9.8
drag_coefficient,    = 1.1
mass                 = 100
cross_sectional_area = 0.7
density              = 1.2690.to_f
```

http://savedbythegoog.appspot.com/?id=5cbe34730e3b56ec97d961704e636bab5da58225

I get the above graph for the acceleration and velocity which seem fine but there is an obvious disconnect between the terminal velocity and the velocity reached by the calculations.

Now at t=40 I change the drag_coefficient and the cross_sectional_area(Which should be a function of t to simulate the opening of the parachute but for testing I've just used a constant value). The changed variables:

```
drag_coefficient,    = 1.9
cross_sectional_area = 35.0
```

I get the following graph (Smaller t increase as the deceleration is insane): http://savedbythegoog.appspot.com/?id=fed3506199191043e94a27060dffc95800c70152

That means he's decelerating in .5 seconds which seems way too high. Is this just because the opening of the parachute is a function of t or am I missing something still.
Any pointers/help is much appreciated.

**Edit:** inlined and simplified code. Original Gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/29e1ed08ad4e0d7d28a0

Comment: This question may be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks p11y. I've changed the question to be more around the essential.

Comment: For `drag_force` you should not be squaring the entire formula - just the velocity.  And for terminal velocity diff, can you clarify what value you are expecting and why?

Comment: I don't believe you can get a reasonable approximation of terminal velocities by doing rough calculations. Air density alone varies a lot with altitude and temperature; what you have is close to the density of dry air at standard temperature (0 °C) and pressure (100 kPa). Also, a surface area of 5 m2 seems too large for chute closed and too small for chute open.  These values suggest a tv of 14.4 m/sec, well below the ~ 55m/s often cited for chute-closed tv, and with chute open, I certainly wouldn't want to land at that speed. I don't see any point doing this without digging into the math.

Comment: Right, good catch Cary. The area was 35m2 for the parachute open and .9 for the normal state. As for the Air density; It seems to range from ~1.2 - ~1.5. In any case I'll update these values to reflect the values I had before I started flailing. And plot these values on a graph to show how the values look when using these calculations.

Comment: Updated; Thanks again PinnyM it's looking a lot better :)

Comment: re air density, I was thinking more the effect of altitude, which is of course correlated with temperature.  An approximation of air density as a function of altitude is given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:StandardAtmosphere.png).  I understand skydivers typically open their chutes at around 1,000m.  at 1,000m, it looks like density is about 90% of the that at sea-level. Note you don't need any of the `to_f`'s above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems here.

First off, your drag coefficient is rather high. Anything over one is high. A poorly designed parachute can have a drag coefficient that exceeds unity. A value of 1.5? "Poorly designed" doesn't even come close to describing how poorly designed that parachute is. A well designed parachute will have a Cd of about 0.75 to 0.9.

Secondly, your parachutist is opening his or her chute on a very cold day at the very bottom of Death Valley. The density of air at sea level at 15 C (~60 F) is 1.225 kg/m<sup>3</sup>. Air density drops rather drastically with increased altitude. If you were using some mathematically inclined language I could point you to a fairly decent model of how pressure, density, and temperature vary with altitude. Google the phrase "standard atmosphere 1976".

There's one minor problem here: You are using ruby. I can't find an implementation of the standard atmosphere model in ruby. If you are mathematically inclined (the math is not that hard), you might want to write a ruby implementation of the standard atmosphere model. Or just stick with a density of 1.225 kg/m<sup>3</sup>. Don't use 1.269 kg/m<sup>3</sup>.

Thirdly, and most importantly, parachutes don't instantly open and expose a drag area of 35 m<sup>2</sup>. It takes some time for the parachute to fully open. If the parachutist is falling rapidly, that deployment time lag might not be enough. Accelerations above 10g (~981 m/sec<sup>2</sup>) can be deadly. Those parachutists who love to free fall for a length of time prior to opening their chutes have parachutes that involve a pilot chute (aka a drogue chute)  and a main chute. The pilot chute opens the main parachute, but along the way it slows the parachutist down a bit.

Finally, your numerical integration is Euler's method. Understanding how Euler's method works is essential to understanding the basics of numerical solution of an initial value problem. Once you understand what it's doing and how it works is the moment you should toss it. Euler's method yields rather bad results.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. I'll start looking into designing a function of t for the drag area of the chute(Which should be enough?). For the record, I'm using C# but I'm more proficient in Ruby so it's a better lang for me to crystallise ideas in. As for the values used; the Cd seems to differ from page to page however I found that for a skydiver is 1~1.4 and it was rather hard to find info about chutes so I used the values found here: http://www2.maths.ox.ac.uk/chebfun/examples/temp/html/SkyDiver.shtml. Finally, I'll start looking into Euler's method and see how I can swap this out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid my physics is far too rusty to comment on the validity of the equations you're using. But this part at least seems oversimplified to me:

```
@velocity += (acceleration * delta_time)
```

Inasmuch as I can recollect, calculating a velocity using force vs air drag (which depends on the velocity) yields a highly non-linear differential equation. So complicated, in fact, that the problem only got approximate solutions for centuries. (It's not from lack of trying: the military were particularly interested in it for ballistics reasons.)

In that light, I sincerely doubt you'll get anything approaching the correct result with a 1s tick function, especially with a constant in there that is expressed in `m/s^2`: you'll end up carting material errors around with every tick.

You *might* get better results by making the tick smaller, so as to get closer to approximating a Riemann integral: it needs to be small enough that the cumulative error from one tick to the next is immaterial compared to the final result. (This is probably not the case at the moment.)

That said, don't hold your breath too long, because your equations might be incorrect too if @Pinny's comment is anything to go by. (Again, my physics is far too rusty to comment on the latter.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Denis. It seems I messed up once I started flailing and changed some of the input variables to non-sense. Furthermore the drag_force was wrong as PinnyM pointed out. For the record the changing the tick to 1s or 20ms changed the acceleration but a factor so I reckon using 20ms is a lot more accurate although the 1 second variant didn't seem that far of the more precise 20ms version. Again thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Novae: I think you should really go as far down as performance allows (1ms or even less). What you're doing amounts to a Riemann style integral. Think of it as averaging your function's value over a small section, and multiplying it by the section's width (your tick). Trouble is, that value plays a part in subsequent values. So you cart an increasingly large error around from a tick to the next. The smaller the tick, the more negligible the cumulative error will be compared to the result. Experiment a bit, and you'll be able to find a reasonable sweet spot of accuracy vs performance.

Comment: Cheers, I'll give that a go and update my question accordingly. The reason for the 20ms limit is that this is my the time of my current update loop. I guess I can easily calculate this x20 in a single loop to improve accuracy as the calculation itself isn't really that intensive.